# Unpivot multiple columns in a large table in MySQL (and perform the equivalent using Hadoop?)

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, unpivot, hortonworks-data-platform

What is the proper way to perform unpivoting multiple columns in a large table using mySQL (which does not have UNPIVOT/PIVOT support)?

My flat table:

```
id  A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3  C1   D1   X  Y  Z and many other columns 
1   10  20  30  100 200 300 0.1 1000  ...
2   5   6   7   0   0   0   0.25   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.001  0
```

And my goal is to keep only rows with non-zero value:
(notice C and D have no value2 and value3) and those XYZ columns are the same for each id

```
id  Name    value1  value2  value3  X  Y  Z
1   A         10    20      30      ...
1   B         100   200     300     
1   C         0.1   0       0
1   D        1000   0       0
2   A          5    6       7
2   C        0.25   0       0
3   C       0.001   0       0
```

---

I am new in SQL and the way I do is to do it step by step by creating a staging table each steps:

```
#1. select only the columns that I need to unpivot
CREATE TABLE staging_1 as
(select id, A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2 from flattable)
----
#2. create all four records for each id
CREATE TABLE staging_2 as
(select id, 'A' as Name, A1 as Value1, A2 as Value2, A3 as Value3 from staging_1)
union all
(select id, 'B', B1, B2, B3 from flattable)
union all
(select id, 'C', C1, 0, 0 from flattable)
union all
(select id, 'D', D1, 0, 0 from flattable)
----
#3. remove those column with zero value
CREATE TABLE staging_3 as
(select id, Name, Value1, Value2, Value3
from staging_2
where (Name in ('A','B') and Value1<>0 and Value2<>0 and Value3<>0) 
or (Name in ('C','D') and Value1<>0)    #only need to check Value1 for C, D
----
#4. join it back with the original data with id
select (all columns but A1,A2,A3...C2 and name, value1,2,3) from flattable
left join staging_3
on flattable.id = staging_3.id
```

However, the last step takes too long as I have around 4M id and many XYZ columns.
Is it a proper way to perform this kind of data manipulation?

Bonus question: My final goal is to perform this task using hadoop, however I am completely new in hadoop, I wish to run this SQL script using Hive (I only know SQL). Does this make sense at all? Or should I write my script directly on hadoop language like Pig/ Hive or whatever? (I am using Hortonworks Sandbox)

Comment: Have you seen Hive's built-in stack() UDF? I think it will do what you are asking combined with lateral view: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inTable-GeneratingFunctions%28UDTF%29